# Two-colourings of the complete graph on n vertices

Tags: graph-theory

The question is:

> Show that there is a two-colouring of the complete graph $K_n$ on $n$ vertices with at most
>
> $\displaystyle {n \choose k} 2^{1-{k \choose 2}}$
>
> monochromatic subgraphs $K_k$.
>
> (Hint: Compute expectation of the number of monochromatic $K_k$. )

I'm confused about what a two-colouring is. Diestel (*Graph Theory*) says a $k$-colouring is a vertex partition into $k$ independent sets. But for $n \geq 2$ I don't see how you can do this on $K_n$. Can someone work out what "two-colouring" means in this context?

If I assume it means colouring each edge one of two colours randomly, I can prove the result. But I don't see why it should mean this. It's just me doing what's easy.

Thanks!

Comment: It could mean coloring each $\it vertex$ one of two colors.

Comment: It means coloring each edge one of two colors. (The other interpretation is clearly false.)

Comment: Why not just clarify with the instructor/professor?

Comment: Shouldn't the terminology of the problem then say _2-edge-coloring_ as the default is usually '... _vertex_ ...' ?

Answer (score 1):

This appears in the classic *probabilistic* proof of existence of the Ramsey number $R(k,k)$, due to Erdos, and is indeed a colouring of the edges.

The wiki page on the [probabilistic method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method) has the proof [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_method#First_example).